# In DC Comics, are the Atlanteans of Greek descent?

Tags: dc, aquaman, atlantis

I recall this being the case, but I can't find evidence for it when looking recently.

This still being the case could be supported by:

1. Having Greek culture and language, architecture, etc
2. Atlantis being a Greek 'myth'
3. They worship and are seemingly under the domain of classical Greek gods, and their cities are named after these gods

I understand that Atlanteans are their own culture and people, but it seemed that early on they were Greek, or very much Greek inspired/adjacent.

Can anyone confirm or deny?

Comment: http://dc.wikia.com/wiki/Atlanteans

Comment: http://images1.wikia.nocookie.net/__cb20110305223135/marvel_dc/images/4/4c/Atlantis_09.jpg

Comment: Given the respective time-frames, it would seem more likely that the Greeks are of Atlantean descent.

Comment: @Mike Scott  Yes, I was just about to suggest that if Atlantean culture seems similar to Greek culture, Greeks should be descended from Atlanteans instead of vice versa.  After all, a number of cranks and cultists have written books suggesting that all ancient cultures were descended from Altantean culture.

Answer (score 1):

The first generation of underwater-dwelling Atlanteans are depicted in [*Superman* no. 129](https://readcomiconline.to/Comic/Superman-1939/Issue-129), in which Lori Lemaris makes her debut appearance.

[image: page 31]

The dress and architecture of the Atlanteans appear similar to that of the ancient Greeks.  However, the people's appearances are not Greek looking at all.  I would conclude that the Atlanteans were culturally, but not racially, similar to the ancient Greeks.